# Problem with subprocess.Popen, Permission denied

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie

I was trying write a simple script to open the Arduino IDE.

```
import subprocess
arduino = "/usr/share/applications/arduino-ardunoide.desktop"
subprocess.Popen(arduino)
```

But i recieve the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have no experience with python nor destributions of linux.
How can i give permition or whatever it need to open the Arduino IDE

Comment: I guess Popen is trying to "execute" on a file that is actually not executable. Perhaps you need to use gtk-launch? https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal

Comment: many thanks, this way works fine `subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])`

Comment: @ChristianBeregula: Congratulations on answering your own question! :) Please consider submitting what you've discovered as "the answer". To do that, simply add it to the "Your Answer" box below. And yes, you are allowed to answer your own question; people in this forum do that regularly. In fact, you can even up-vote your own answer, and be recognized for it.